# Ubuntu 20.04 Pantheon-files, there is no color change icon on right click

Tags: 20.04

I am using pantheon-files on ubuntu 20.04.
It is a nice explorer. But when I install it. I am not getting a color change option on right-click over any file. As you can see in the attached image

**An image where I was expecting, Color icon on right-click**

[image]

**An Image, How the was suppose to be available.**

[image]

I am looking forward to hearing anything.
Thanks in advance for any kind of support

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution,
Actually, we are missing some dependency. We need to install those first and restart pc
Again try to install this file package. Now, you can see the color change on right-click

I am sharing commands bellow. But make sure, you check for the latest file first.

At first, you need to enable universe repository with

`sudo add-apt-repository universe`

and then you can manually download and install a newer version of the library with

`cd ~/Downloads wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/libc/libcloudproviders/libcloudproviders0_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb`

`sudo apt install ./libcloudproviders0_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb`

and then install pantheon-files with

`Sudo apt-get install pantheon-files`